# How to set normal window as parent window?

Tags: c#, wpf, window

I am using WPF with c#, I have a trouble when creating a Parent Window in WPF window. I need how to set a parent window?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the [`Owner`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.owner.aspx) property of the child window to the parent window.